# Symmetry in inequalities.

Tags: inequality

I previously asked a question [Is Symmetry a valid option in Inequalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883772/is-symmetry-a-valid-option-in-inequalities).
After some thinking I concluded something:

Some theorem which I made up:[Call it my theorem :D]

> Let $f$ be a diffrentiable,unbounded,multivariate function of n variables with real domain.If $f$ is symmetric*, 
>   Then the minimum/maximum must occur at the point where all variables are equal,. For if $f$ is bounded the solutions may exist at the bounds.

Can need someone prove/disprove the statement, or prove a modified form of it with other minor restrictions.Best way would be some contracdictions, if it cannot be proved at all.

*By symmetric I mean all permutations of variables in the function give us the same expression.

I say so because, let the equation be:
$$f(x,y,z)=xy+yz+zx$$
It is symmetric because:
$$f(x,y,z)=f(x,z,y)=\cdots=f(z,y,x)$$

Now my thinking can be attributed to two further reasons:

- If we get the minimum/maximum value of function at a particular set of values say $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ then $\beta,\alpha,\gamma$ will also satisfy the equation. Letting all three values equal i.e. $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$ we might get a minimum/maximum.
- $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0,\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$ all have same roots thus minimum/maximum might occur at point where all vaiables are equal.

Some more examples[All from MSE inequalitis section]:

> - $\displaystyle f=xyz-xy-yx-zx$, $x+y+z=1$ when $x=y=z=1/3$ minimum i.e. $-8/27$
> - $\displaystyle f=\frac{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}{(x+y+z)\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}}$,minimum when $x=y=z$ i.e. $8/3$
> - $\displaystyle f=\sum_{cyc} \frac{\sqrt{xy}}{\sqrt{xy+z}}\le\frac{3}{2}$, $x+y+z=1$ minimum when $x=y=z=1/3$ i.e. $3/2$
> - $\displaystyle f=a^3+b^3+c^3- a^2+b^2+c^2$, $ab+bc+ca\le 3abc$ minimum when $a=b=c$ i.e. $0$
> - $\displaystyle f=\sum{\frac{1}{(x+2y)^2}} -\frac{1}{xy+yz+zx}$, minimum when $x=y=z$ i.e. $0$
> - $\displaystyle f=(a+b+c)(1/a+1/b+1/c)$, minimum when $a=b=c$ i.e. $9$
> - $\displaystyle f=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(b+c-a)^4}{a(a+b-c)}-(ab+bc+ca)$,  minimum when $a=b=c$ i.e. $0$

Comment: Is this a good counterexample $f(a,b) = ((a-1)^2 + (b-2)^2)((a-2)^2+(b-1)^2)$  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=extrema+%28%28a-1%29%5E2+%2B+%28b-2%29%5E2%29%28%28a-2%29%5E2%2B%28b-1%29%5E2%29

Comment: What do you do if the function is constant?

Comment: @Taro can you give some example

Comment: @ganeshie8 yes it is

Comment: @Aditya Sorry, I missed your condition 'unbounded'.

Comment: @ganeshie8 but there must be some logic to equality of variables as seen in these x,y,z and a,b,c type of polynomial inequalities, there is some characteristic to them

Comment: yeah im trying to get a good feel of the same :) Also the counterexample provided above is not a strong case as there is a symmetry in solutions too :  (1,2) and (2,1) both give minimum value

Comment: You are looking for a version of the Purkiss Principle. See http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/do-symmetric-problems-have-symmetric-solutions as mentioned in the linked problem. The solution need not be when the variables are equal as shown there. The solution set though would be symmetric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modified version of this is definitely true:

**Purkiss Principle:**

> Let $f$ and $g$ be symmetric functions with continuos second derivatives in the neighbourhood of a point $P=(r,r,r,...,r)$. On the set where $g$ equals $g(P)$, the function $f$ will have a local macimum or minimum at $P$ except in degenerate cases.

**Link:**

> [**"Do symmetric problems have symmetric solutions?"**](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Waterhouse378-387.pdf)
>  by **William C.Waterhouse**
>  *Department of Mathematics, The Pennsylvania State University, University Park, PA 16802*

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler counterexample.

$$f(x, y) = x^4 + y^4 - x^2 - y^2$$

It takes its minimum at four points. Though those points are placed 'symmetrically', two points have 'non-symmetric' coordinates.
[image: minimum]

Comment: see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=extrema+x%5E4+++y%5E4+-+x%5E2+-+y%5E2) no global maxima or minima but local maximum at $x=y=0$

Comment: search "extrema x^4 +  y^4 - x^2 - y^2" on w|a to see symmetry

Comment: This function has no maximum and has minimum at four points which indicated by green points in the graph.